# Filtering Data Table Row Vector That Lies Between 2 Numeric Vectors

Tags: r

I have a data.table (df) that looks similar to this:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
ID AltID   Crit1   Crit2   Crit3
1  1       1       5       10
1  2       3       7       15
1  3       2       6       11')
```

and for each `Crit`-column I have an upper and lower bound like this:

```
minCutoff = c(0, 5, 10)
maxCutoff = c(4, 7, 12)
```

that are calculated from data.table (df).

I'd like a function which excludes any row where one value is out of bounds. In addition I'd like this function to work with a variable number of `Crit` columns (e.g. 3 Crit columns, 4 Crit columns, etc.) since my input data is subject to change.

So for this example, rows 1 and 3 would be kept but row 2 would be discarded since its `Crit3 (15) > maxCutoff (12)` despite `Crit1` and `Crit2` being within the acceptable ranges. The output would therefore be:

```
ID AltID   Crit1   Crit2   Crit3
1  1       1       5       10
1  3       2       6       11
```

I've tried solving this using a `for` loop to count the number of columns I have and then a nested for loop to iterate over the rows using something like...

```
for (c in 1:(ncol(df)-2)+2) 
{
    for (r in 1:nrow(df)) 
    {
     between(df[r,c], minCutoff[c], maxCutoff[c])
    }
}
```

*The `ncol(df)-2)+2` is due to working around the ID columns

However, now I have a TON of T/F values that I'm having trouble aggregating to determine whether a row should be kept or discarded.

I'm sure there's a magical R way of making this process simpler, but I'm not skilled enough to see it.

If anyone has any tips, tricks, or other threads to point me in the right direction I'd be mighty grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Nice that you describe your problem in so much detail. But here it seems to much to me. Please edit your question and include an example of what kind of output you expect. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"where any 3 columns fall outside the range"* is not compatible with *"row 2 would be discarded"*. Row 2 has only one column that is outside its range, so it should not be filtered out. Please update your sample data, your rules, or your expected output.

Comment: Thanks, edit make. Hopefully, that clarifies things a little better

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions 5th. Question should read a little shorter now. Also included code that Rui and r2evans used to make the df I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
ID AltID   Crit1   Crit2   Crit3
1  1       1       5       10
1  2       3       7       15
1  3       2       6       11')
minCutoff = c(0, 5, 10)
maxCutoff = c(4, 7, 12)
```

---

TL;DR:

```
df[rowSums(mapply(between, df[ grep("Crit", colnames(df)) ], minCutoff, maxCutoff)) >= 3,]
#   ID AltID Crit1 Crit2 Crit3
# 1  1     1     1     5    10
# 3  1     3     2     6    11
```

---

Having a variable number of `Crit` columns is easily handled with a function to apply to each in turn, and then aggregate the results. If you are already using the `dplyr` package, then you already have `dplyr::between`, but if not then here is an acceptable replacement:

```
between <- function(x, low, hi) low <= x & x <= hi
```

I'll walk you through the work:

```
isbetween <- mapply(between, df[ grep("Crit", colnames(df)) ], minCutoff, maxCutoff)
isbetween
#      Crit1 Crit2 Crit3
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

- `df[grepl("Crit", colnames(df)) ]` is one way (of several) for looking at *just* the columns that are of interest to you;
- `mapply` applies a function (`between`, in this case) with the first value of each of the other lists/vectors. It is effectively the same as:

  ```
  between(df[3], minCutoff[1], maxCutoff[1])
  between(df[4], minCutoff[2], maxCutoff[2])
  ...
  ```

Now that we have a logical matrix of individual values within their respective cutoffs, we an look at each row to check if they meet your filter requirements of 3 or more. Unfortunately, your listed expected output is not compatible with your rules, so I'll offer some alternatives:

- *"where any 3 columns fall outside the range"*, meaning if 3 or more columns are `FALSE`, then the row should be removed

  ```
  rowSums(!isbetween) >= 3
  # [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ```
- *"where at least 3 columns fall inside the range"*, which is what your expected output suggests:

  ```
  rowSums(isbetween) >= 3
  # [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  ```

Regardless of which you choose, take this logical vector and subset the rows, such as

```
df[rowSums(isbetween) >= 3,]
#   ID AltID Crit1 Crit2 Crit3
# 1  1     1     1     5    10
# 3  1     3     2     6    11
```

(The biggest difference between [Rui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770849/3358272) and this is that that answer uses `apply` on a `data.frame` for row-wise operations, implicitly converting the involved columns into a matrix. My answer works column-wise (natural operation with frames), so no conversion is done. Other than this conversion, if the frame is not huge then the performance of row-wise versus column-wise should be roughly the same. If it is largely assymmetric (e.g., many many more rows than columns), then it might be a little faster to work column-wise. Vectorized work in R is almost always much faster than iterative.)

Comment: Oh cool, thanks r2evans (especially for the walk-through). My minimized example only has 3 rows, but my real-life dataset (which I didn't mention in the original question) has ~1M rows so your solution works better/quicker for my dataset.

Comment: Glad the walk-through helped. For feedback: your question was good and thorough (data and code!), and though it could have been shortened a bit, it wasn't too bad IMO. Providing sample data is critical and your method sufficed this time; my method is one of [several listed under "reproducible questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/), also including `dput(head(...`, `data.frame(...`, etc. The latter are nice because there is no ambiguity in each column's `class`, where your method and mine would mask `factor`s and `POSIX`, among other things.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an external package just to use `between`, base R can do what you want.

```
minCutoff <- c(0, 5, 10)
maxCutoff <- c(4, 7, 12)

cols <- grep("^Crit", names(df))

inx <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) all(minCutoff <= x & x <= maxCutoff))
df[inx, ]
#  ID AltID Crit1 Crit2 Crit3
#1  1     1     1     5    10
#3  1     3     2     6    11
```

**DATA.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID AltID   Crit1   Crit2   Crit3
1  1       1       5       10
1  2       3       7       15
1  3       2       6       11
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You suggest using `between` (which is not base R, btw) but it is not in your code.

Comment: @r2evans No, you misunderstood what I wrote. (Or I am the one that explained myself poorly.) `between` is an external package which is not needed, base R can do it.

Comment: RyanEller, the note of using `apply` with a `data.frame` is that you correctly subset the columns so that they are all of compatible classes. If for instance one of them is a `character`, then the data seen by the anonymous function will be a vector of strings, not numbers, which has tripped up many people. Rui did it right, but know that `apply` always converts to a `matrix` internally.

Comment: Sorry, Rui, I see it now. I saw the OP's `for` loop and instantly tuned out the code inside of it :-)

Comment: That works perfectly, especially with my changing column numbers. Thanks Rui and r2evans for the help! Would have been at this all day otherwise. And thanks Rui for the Data example, should have put that in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

As the dataset is `data.table`, we can use `data.table` methods.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table with `lapply`, apply the logic to get a logical vector, `Reduce` it to a single logical vector by comparing corresponding elements of each column and use it to filter the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x > minCutoff & 
              x < maxCutoff)), .SDcols = Crit1:Crit3]]
#    ID AltID Crit1 Crit2 Crit3
#1:  1     1     1     5    10
#2:  1     3     2     6    11
```

Comment: Does this deal with the "*3 columns*" constraint? I like `Reduce(\`|\`, ...`, but that suggests "any", not "non-1" limit.

Comment: If the condition is like that `setDT(df1)[df1[, Reduce('+', Map(function(x, y, z) x >=y & x <= z, .SD, minCutoff, maxCutoff)) ==3, .SDcols = Crit1:Crit3]]`